# I getting error like this (node:4040) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated

Tags: reactjs

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (E:\appfronted\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\appfronted\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
at handleParseError (E:\appfronted\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:434:10)
at E:\appfronted\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:466:5
at E:\appfronted\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:12
at E:\appfronted\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (E:\appfronted\node_modules\webpack

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.